# Eclipse: Preserve uncollapsed paths in package explorer on restart

Tags: eclipse, ide, package-explorer

I am a bit tired of reopening all the paths I am currently working on in my package explorer every time I restart eclipse.

Is there a way to tell eclipse to save my package explorer state i.e. not to collapse everything on closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you toggle the "Link with Editor" button the path to your last used file will be restored.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

Package Explorer does not save the tree state when it closes so there is no way that it can be restored.

Comment: In my opinion this is more than a mild annoyance. It is simply an unnecessary and repetetive task. Since I have not found a similar question anywhere: Why is this not needed? Is there a way around this or is indeed everybody uncollapsing his entire tree every time?